# How to automatically .format() user's input into a string, in Python?

Tags: python, string, input, string.format

How could I automatically take a user's input and .format() it into a string? For example: when the user inputs their name, I would like to automatically insert their name into a string that greets them by their first name.

Comment: you're going to need to elaborate some more on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: By writing some code, I'd assume.

Comment: If you're using python 2.*, the following would: `print "Hello, ", raw_input()` meet your purpose.

Comment: In case it's not clear to the OP: this question is getting a bad reaction because it involves two steps that are trivial to look up on this site: (1) getting user input as string and (2) using `.format()`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
a = raw_input('') #python 2.x
a = input('') #python 3.x
print("Greetings {}".format(a))
```

Comment: I like how you made separate `input`s for python 2 and 3, but then used the python2-only `print` without parentheses.

Comment: Shame on me :) 2.7 4life!